# Kotlin Android print to console

Tags: android, printing, kotlin

I need to print some str to console (Android Studio) using Kotlin.
I've tried the:

```
Log.v() 
Log.d() 
Log.i() 
Log.w() 
Log.e()
```

methods. But it seems to work only on Java.
What should I use to print using Kotlin?
Thanks

Comment: Any Java methods work with Kotlin too. What exactly do you mean by "it seems to work"?

Comment: Btw: You can use the log templates to generate the code in Java and convert it automatically to Kotlin by copy and pasting it into a Kotlin file. Or, you can make the log templates available in Kotlin by importing the Kotlin port from [this Github repo](https://github.com/TobiasUhmann/android-studio-log-templates-for-kotlin) directly. Just import the .jar via 'File > Import Settings...'.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.

**You can use `Log.d("TAG", "message");` for example but first you need to import *Log***.

```
import android.util.Log

{...}

Log.d("TAG", "message")

{...}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

**You can also use kotlin's *print* and *println* function.**

Example:

```
{...}

print("message")

println("other message")

{...}
```

Source: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/

Comment: Kotlin's print and println functions do not print to the Android log.

Comment: True, they print to the standard output as stated in the docs I setup as source. But the question was in fact about printing to console, not necessarily the android log. I guess it still fits =)

Comment: @Ramalus The original question had an `Android` tag, but it's good to include both I suppose.

Comment: Using `Log.d(TAG, message)` is a bit annoying. https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber makes it easier.

Comment: print() is not working in console, but println() is working why? can anybody explain.

Comment: @UNREAL println() prints your log in a new line, that's why you notice it, while print() prints in the end of the current line, which make all logs print in the same line with other logs, which is harder to notice and read

Answer (score 10):

I've written some extension functions that make use of reified type parameters in order to avoid dealing with declaring log tags in all project's classes. The basic idea is shown by the following snippet:

```
inline fun <reified T> T.logi(message: String) = Log.i(T::class.java.simpleName, message)
```

Basically, you can log something to the logcat with the following invocation (W/O external dependencies):

```
logi("My log message")
```

You can find a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/paolop/0bd59e49b33d18d6089fb1bf5488e212). The functions declared in the gist are a little more elaborated given that they allow:

- Lazy evaluation of the string to be logged out (if for example the string needs to be generated in some way)
- Logging only when in debug mode by default
- Use a given class name when you need to log from within an anonymous class that has no name

Comment: Interesting solution. I don't know you can define dynamic class method like that.

Answer (score 7):

At this moment (android studio 2.3.3 with Kotlin plugin),

```
Log.i(TAG, "Hello World")
```

Just works. It will import `android.util.Log`

Answer (score 5):

androidKotlin is deprecated and use [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/) instead.

https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Logging

```
class SomeActivity : Activity(), AnkoLogger {
    private fun someMethod() {
        info("London is the capital of Great Britain")
        debug(5) // .toString() method will be executed
        warn(null) // "null" will be printed
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated in the README of the linked library, it is deprecated. [Anko](https://github.com/kotlin/anko) should be used instead.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't noticed that part. I will update the answer

Comment: >Anko is deprecated. Please see this page for more information.
https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Anko`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) library to do it. You would have code like below:

```
class MyActivity : Activity(), AnkoLogger {
    private fun someMethod() {
        info("This is my first app and it's awesome")
        debug(1234) 
        warn("Warning")
    }
}
```

or you can also use this small written in Kotlin library called [`StaticLog`](https://github.com/jupf/staticlog) then your code would looks like:

```
Log.info("This is an info message")
Log.debug("This is a debug message")
Log.warn("This is a warning message","WithACustomTag")
Log.error("This is an error message with an additional Exception for output", "AndACustomTag", exception )

Log.logLevel = LogLevel.WARN
Log.info("This message will not be shown")\
```

The second solution might better if you would like to define an output format for logging method like:

```
Log.newFormat {
    line(date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), space, level, text("/"), tag, space(2), message, space(2), occurrence)
}
```

or use filters, for example:

```
Log.filterTag = "filterTag"
Log.info("This log will be filtered out", "otherTag")
Log.info("This log has the right tag", "filterTag")
```

If you already used Jake Wharton's `Timber` logging library check this project: https://github.com/ajalt/timberkt.

Check also: [Logging in Kotlin & Android: AnkoLogger vs kotlin-logging](https://medium.com/@OhadShai/logging-in-android-ankologger-vs-kotlin-logging-bb693671442a#.ngk3r66et)

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```kotlin
Log.i("info message")
Log.d("debug message")
Log.w("warning message","warningOutPut")
Log.e("error message","AndACustomTag",exception)
```

You can write them with kotlin too.